# SELECT chaining the result of two queries on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I want to chain the contents of two queries. Please notice I DON'T want to use `CONCAT()` or `CONCAT_WS()` because that's not what I want to achieve.

Query 1 results:

```
Id    Name
1     John
2     Mike
```

Query 2 results:

```
Id    Name
3     Emily
7     Robert
```

And what I want is:

```
Id    Name
1     John
2     Mike
3     Emily
7     Robert
```

I can also rewrite both queries as one. That would be great. Here are my current failed attempts:

```
SELECT a.x AS x, a.y AS y FROM a;
SELECT b.x AS x, b.y AS y FROM b;
```

Thank you.

Comment: welcome to Stackoverflow! If you haven't [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) yet, please do so! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) to join multiple queries to a single result set:

```
SELECT a.x AS x, a.y AS y FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.x AS x, b.y AS y FROM b
```

**NOTE**

`UNION ALL` will preserve all redundancies. please read the manual page and modify the query to achieve your desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.x AS x, a.y AS y FROM a
union all
SELECT b.x AS x, b.y AS y FROM b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT a.x AS x, a.y AS y FROM a
UNION ALL
SELECT b.x AS x, b.y AS y FROM b;
```

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

How about using union?

```
SELECT a.x AS x, a.y AS y 
FROM a
UNION
SELECT b.x AS x, b.y AS y 
FROM b;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want an union:

```
SELECT a.x AS x, a.y AS y FROM a 
UNION
SELECT b.x AS x, b.y AS y FROM b
```

If you want possible redundancies to be preserved use UNION ALL.